# Per channel Normalization pytorch or Keras

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, pytorch, computer-vision

For the medical images, I have to normalize each image's channel one by one. So for that, I created this code :

```
def normalizeImage(paths):
    img = cv2.imread(paths)
    normImg = np.zeros(img.shape)
    k = 0

    for i in range(img.shape[2]):
        if(img[:, :, i].std() != 0):
            normImg[:, :, i] = (img[:, :, i] - img[:, :, i].mean()) / (img[:, :, i].std())
            k +=1
            # print(k)
            if k ==3:
                array_list.append(normImg)
    return normImg
```

then converting them to tensors:

```
tensor_x = torch.Tensor(np.array(array_list))
tensor_y = ....
my_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y) 
my_dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset,batch_size=16)
```

However, I couldn't continue after that. I have three directories (binary classification):

train: wound/ no_wound

test

val

I am open to applying new methods. How can I do that for the whole dataset?

```
        if(img[:, :, i].std() != 0):
            normImg[:, :, i] = (img[:, :, i] - img[:, :, i].mean()) / (img[:, :, i].std())
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to normalize them one by one, on a per-image basis?

Comment: My professor wants it, I showed her several methods but she insisted on that. :(

Comment: Your code is working, but you want it faster? What does it means "I can't continue after that"?

Comment: Why `pathS` instead of `path`? it is a list of paths, and you want to run your code on all the paths? Is `paths` a folder and you want to pick all the files on the folder?

Comment: My code is working yes, but it is okay for one path. for ex: paths = "....\train\no_wound". But I want it for the whole dataset. Is it clear?